# C++ Arrays and writing of values

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

I'm trying to write a punnett square generator for a biology class, it's quite simple, but I can't figure out how to get the values to write to the other blocks. I can get the individual variables in, but I can't get the values to combine in the lower squares. Any help would be appreciated. Code is attached below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char p_s[2][2] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    cout << "Input first parent's first gene.\n";
    cin >> p_s[i][j];
    j++;
    cout << "Input first parent's sencond gene.\n";
    cin >> p_s[i][j];
    system("Pause");
    cout << "First Gene: " << p_s[0][1] << endl << endl << "Second Gene: " << p_s[0][2];
    j = 0;
    i++;
    cout << endl << endl << "Input second parent's first gene: ";
    cin >> p_s[i][j];
    i++;
    cout << "Input second parent's second gene: ";
    cin >> p_s[i][j];
    cout << "First Gene: " << p_s[1][0] << endl << endl << "Second Gene: " << p_s[0][2];
    system("PAUSE");
    p_s[1][1] = p_s[0][1] p_s[1][0];
    cout << p_s[1][1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When j is 2, `[j]` is out of bounds.

Comment: are we suppose to do your homework for you?

Comment: It runs just fine, though.

Comment: It does not run fine.  2 lines above return 0 is a syntax error.  Maybe you forgot an equals sign?

Comment: @MichaelMelton _"It runs just fine, though"_ So what you're bothering about??

Comment: `p_s[0][2]` and `p_s[1][0]` are the same location

Comment: I'm asking about how to get the data from p_s[0][1] and p_s[1][0] to both be in p_s [1][1].  Like how a punnett square actually works.

Comment: @MichaelMelton Ok, so let me clarify.  What exactly do you mean by BOTH?  Do you mean you want both letters from [0][1] and [1][0] to be in [1][1]?

Comment: @Ben Yup. That's exactly right. So if [0][1] had "A" and [1][0] had "a", I would want [1][1] to be "Aa".

Comment: You can't do it in your current program.  You have chosen your array to be a char array.  That means you can only store a single character at each location.  You need to rethink the design of your program.

Comment: OR, you could map a certain char which you will never use to mean the same thing as 2 characters, like Yy could be mapped to the letter z.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. That does. As far as rethinking the design, no. It doesn't.

Comment: Well as you can see from the first answer, now you see what I meant by rethinking your design.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see a problem with `int j`:

In line three you initialize it to one

```
int j = 1;
```

Three lines later you increment it up by one:

```
j++; // j is now equal to 2
//...
cin >> p_s[i][j]; // j is still equal to 2, which is outside of the array bounds!
```

This same thing happens in lines 10 and 18, where you attempt to access `p_s[0][2]`, which is outside of the array's bounds.

Also, if you're looking to make a traditional punnett square, each square would require two `char`'s worth of storage, which just isn't available with your current system (You'd need 8 `char`'s, and `p_s` only has four).

However, if you were looking to revise your program, you could always try an object oriented approach, by splitting your punnett and parents into classes like this:

```
struct Parent
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;

    Parent(std::string _a, std::string _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
}
```

And

```
struct Punnett
{
    std::vector<std::string> GeneCombos;

    Punnett (Parent one, Parent two) {
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.a + two.a);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.a + two.b);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.b + two.a);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.b + two.b);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the values of the Punnett square: They're created in the constructor.

If you wanted to go a step further, you could add to the constructors of both classes to make them assign their variables based on user input:

```
struct Parent
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;

    Parent(std::string _a, std::string _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}

    Parent() { //If no values are passed, it asks for them
        std::cout << "\nEnter Gene One: ";
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "\nEnter Gene Two: ";
        std::cin >> b;
    }
};
```

And for the Punnett class:

```
class Punnett
{
    std::vector<std::string> GeneCombos;

public:
    void draw() {
        std::cout << "\nResulting Combinations:\n";
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            std::cout << GeneCombos[i] << '\n';
    }

    Punnett (Parent one, Parent two) {
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.a + two.a);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.a + two.b);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.b + two.a);
        GeneCombos.push_back(one.b + two.b);
    }
};
```

Using the modified classes, your main() would only be five lines long:

```
int main()
{
    Parent One;
    Parent Two;
    Punnett punnett(One, Two);
    punnett.draw();
    return 0;
}
```

Hoped this helped.

EDIT*: As Ben Voigt wisely pointed out, the Punnett::draw() function didn't belong in the constructor, and was moved to main().

Comment: Except that `draw()` should be called from `main()`, not the `Punnett` constructor... since it does not help with construction in any way.